# Why does an inaccessible cardinal satisfy replacement?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

If $\alpha$ is an inaccessible cardinal and $V_{\alpha}$ the corresponding von Neumann universe then $V_{\alpha}$ is supposed to be a model of ZFC.  But the singleton $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ is not in $V_{\alpha}$ because it has rank greater than $\alpha$.  There is a bijection $\{1\} \to \{V_{\alpha}\}$ that sends $1$ to $V_{\alpha}$ so replacement should say that $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ is a "set", i.e., $\{V_{\alpha}\} \in V_{\alpha}$.  Thus I've reached a contradiction.

I'm very new to thinking about set theory and I'm sure I've done something wrong because I misunderstood some definition or something.  If anyone could set me straight I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try writing down explicitely the formula you want to apply replacement to, to see what goes wrong

Comment: Also note that to have $V_\alpha\vDash \text{Replacement}$ it's enough for $\alpha$ to be a strong limit ($\lambda<\alpha\implies 2^\lambda<\alpha$)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Surely you mean that it is *possible* for $V_\alpha$ to satisfy replacement if $\alpha$ is a singular strong limit cardinal, not that it always does.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti . If GCH and $a=\omega_{\omega}$ then $a$ is a strong limit but $V_a$ does not satisfy Replacement.

Comment: Woops, I forgot a "regular" (in hindsight that was a very convoluted way to also include $\omega$ with the inaccessibles and could have been phrased way better)

Comment: @Daniel Or just $\beth_\omega,$ or any cardinal that doesn’t enjoy a variety of medium cardinal properties like being a Beth fixed point, being a fixed point of the enumeration of fixed points, etc.

Comment: @Alessandro yeah, that is a good point for OP: forget inaccessible cardinals, this argument would work just as well to show $V_\omega$ would violate replacement. (In fact it’s more disastrous than that since it would show no set whatsoever could be a transitive model of replacement.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That $V_\alpha$ satisfies replacement means that $V_\alpha$ thinks there is a set that is $\{F(x)\mid x\in A\}$ whenever $A\in V_\alpha$ and $F$ is a class function **that can be expressed in $V_\alpha$**.

The latter condition means that the logical formula that represents $F$ is to be interpreted with all quantifiers ranging over $V_\alpha$ itself, and all parameters being elements of $V_\alpha$.

You cannot write your bijection $\{1\mapsto V_\alpha\}$ as a class function within $V_\alpha$ -- there's no way to even *speak* about the property of "being $V_\alpha$" for the function value, with a formula that's interpreted within $V_\alpha$ itself.

Comment: Ahh, now I see.  Thank you for the explanation :)